# Why auto generated url is giving 404

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a backend api which listen for  `/assets` with some query parameters

this kind of call always works

`/assets?id=1&type=filter`

`/assets?type=filter&id=1`

BUT this kind url throws `404`

`/assets&id=1?type=filter`

`/assets&type=filter?id=1`

**Question:** how to make this kind of url `/assets&type=filter?id=1` in correct format

Comment: You shall always have `?` before the first parameter. If you have some code that generates `/assets&id=1?type=filter` then it's not working correct

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Ya that i understood, but url is generating somewhere else in the code, before sending it to a api i want  it to be corrected as you said with some code.

Comment: Then you have to find the code that generates the wrong URLs and fix it...

Comment: @JordiNebot purposely i'm not generating wrong url, it is happening with some old code. so i wanted to correct it.

Comment: Isn't that _old code_ part of your project? If  for any reason you can't access the old code to make sure it generates correct URLs, then you should replace the `&` and `?` characters accordingly as others suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters take the form of a `?` followed by a set of key=value pairs separated by `&` characters. The `?` and `&` are not interchangeable.

Whatever method you are using to construct the URLs (which you haven't shown us but I assume involves mashing strings together): stop. Use [the URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instead.

```js
const url = new URL('/assets', location);
url.searchParams.append('id', 1);
url.searchParams.append('type', 'filter');
console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: i will not be having absolute url i will be having proxy url  like this `/api/assets&type=filter?id=1`   `api` will be substituted in `nginx` like this

`location /api/{
     proxy_pass  http://192.148.1.185:9003/;
}`

`new URL('/assets');` will throw error without absolute path

Comment: Then I'd do something like `const url = new URL('/assets', 'http://example.com'); /* ... */ return url.toString().replace('http://example.com', '')`

Comment: Your above comment helped me to solve my problem, for above comment i will acept your answer

Answer (score 0):

`/assets&id=1?type=filter`

`/assets&type=filter?id=1`

These are invalid url formats. To pass your query params you should at the end of url add `?`, and then use `&` to add more query params